# how java unirest to set content-length

Tags: java, unirest

java.

I use `Unirest.post` to post my multipart data. but server shows error to me:

> multipart: NextPart: EOF.

I find that, if I set `Content-Length` I can solve this.

Here the code:

```
String buff = "my data";
HttpResponse<String> res = Unirest.post(url)
    .header("Content-Type", multipart.getContentType().getValue())
    .header("Content-Length", String.valueOf(buff.length()))
    .body(buff).asString();
```

But after I add  `.header("Content-Length", String.valueOf(buff.length()))`, run java I get error:

> org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the earlier set content length so that you can set a new one.

@John Rix's answer This code helped solved the problem

```
private static class ContentLengthHeaderRemover implements HttpRequestInterceptor{
            @Override
            public void process(HttpRequest request, HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
                request.removeHeaders(HTTP.CONTENT_LEN);// fighting org.apache.http.protocol.RequestContent's ProtocolException("Content-Length header already present");
            }
        }
HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
                .addInterceptorFirst(new ContentLengthHeaderRemover())
                .build();
```